# Postgresql: Cast result between parentheses

Tags: postgresql

I'm new to postgresql and I'm stuck on a school exercise. 
I'm supossed to convert a integer value to only getting the first number between parentheses and adding it behind a name.
Withouth parentheses I've got this:

```
SELECT (name ||' '|| CAST(playernumber AS CHAR(1))
```

But I can't seem to get the result of that cast between parentheses.
So instead of the result being: name firstnumber
It should be: name (firstnumber).

The solution is probably pretty simple, but I just can't seem to find it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `SELECT name ||' ('|| playernumber || ')'` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `concat()` which also properly deals with NULL values:

```
concat_ws(name, ' (', playernumber, ')')
```